# count number of duplicates in a list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a list like:

```
let lst = ["cat"; "dog"; "cow"; "dog"; "cat"; "horse"; "dog"];;
```

I want to count the number of same elements and have the output in a list of tuples (element, count) like:

```
[("cat", 2); ("dog", 3); ("cow", 1); ("horse", 1)]
```

I tried using `List.fold_left` but found that the folding function will be complex. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about performance, then it can be like this:

```
let count_dup l =
  let scan_count x l = List.fold_left (fun (c,acc) y -> if x = y then c+1,acc else c,y::acc) (1,[]) l in
  let rec count acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd::tl -> let c,r = scan_count hd tl in count ((hd,c)::acc) r
  in 
  count [] l
```

---

If you care about performance, but don't care about the order, then it is better that you sort the list first, then scan once.

```
let count_dup' l = 
  let sl = List.sort compare l in
  match sl with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> 
      let acc,x,c = List.fold_left (fun (acc,x,c) y -> if y = x then acc,x,c+1 else (x,c)::acc, y,1) ([],hd,1) tl in
      (x,c)::acc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let count l =
    let hash = Hashtbl.create 10 in
    List.iter (fun key -> if Hashtbl.mem hash key then Hashtbl.replace hash key ((Hashtbl.find hash key) + 1) else Hashtbl.add hash key 1) l;
    Hashtbl.fold (fun k v ls -> (k, v) :: ls) hash []
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to preserve order and performance:

```
    let count lst = 
      let sorted = List.sort (compare) lst in
      List.fold_right (fun ele acc -> match acc with 
                                      | [] -> [(ele, 1)]
                                      | (ele', c)::t -> 
                                           if ele = ele' 
                                           then (ele, c+1)::t
                                           else (ele,1)::(ele',c)::t) sorted []
```

Comment: You compute a sorted list but don't use it in the rest of the code. Also your code gets this result for OP's test case: `[("cat", 1); ("dog", 1); ("cow", 1); ("dog", 1); ("cat", 1); ("horse", 1);
 ("dog", 1)]`

Comment: Good catch! I should have used sorted not lst in the end.

Comment: Aha, I get it. Your code returns a sorted order (the reverse order of Jackson Tale's second solution). But Jackson Tale is talking about preserving the *original* order of the elements. It's not hard to get any desired *sorted* order in the result. E.g., just sort into reverse order in Jackson Tale's second solution (`let revcompare a b = compare b a`). Preserving the original order is harder.

Comment: Oh I see now, thats an interesting problem